# Tag for [BigMemory] on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I have just created the [bigmemory](/questions/tagged/bigmemory) tag for the [BigMemory](http://www.terracotta.org/products/bigmemory) extension to Ehcache from Terracotta.

**I don’t like this tag name!!**  Any ideas for a better tag name?

---

The tag has now been renamed to  [ehcache-bigmemory](/questions/tagged/ehcache-bigmemory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make it more clear that it is about the Ehcache extension, you could rename it to [ehcache-bigmemory](/questions/tagged/ehcache-bigmemory).

Comment: Thanks, I have just flag the quesion asking a mod to rename the tag

Comment: You don't need a mod.  Since there is only one question, you can just retag it yourself.

Comment: @SLaks, how given it has a tag wiki etc, I would recreate the tag wiki on the new tag but then it would need to be appoved again.

Comment: True; I forgot about that.  I merged them.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>The name sounds perfectly reasonable for a technology that's called BigMemory. Whether or not that name is a smart idea is another question and outside the scope of SO ;-)</strike>

Edit: Given that there's at least [one more project called bigmemory](http://www.bigmemory.org/) with a reasonable Google rank out there, I too endorse using [ehcache-bigmemory](/questions/tagged/ehcache-bigmemory) instead of [bigmemory](/questions/tagged/bigmemory).

Are you afraid that it'll be used to refer to systems with lots of memory? Then add a nice Tag Wiki and excerpt.

Comment: I have added a Tag Wiki, but I still think it may just get used for systems with lots of memory, or another product will come out with the same name.